# How to use libraries like pylevenshtein after download?

Tags: python, installation, libraries, levenshtein-distance

How should I go about using a python library that can be downloaded (eg. in the link below)? Haven't used any specific direct written libraries in python before.

http://code.google.com/p/pylevenshtein/

Comment: usually, you install the library (`<sudo> python setup.py install`) and then you can import it.

Comment: Thanks @mgilson ...I needed to install python-dev(sudo apt-get install python-dev) before the command could work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Preferable way to install new libraries in python is to use [pip installer](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html). Install it with the instructions provided in the previous link, and after that you can install new packages by simply typing in console:

```
pip install <package_name>
```

The package you need to install has the name of `python-Levenshtein`.